# Stripe Checkout Input Not Showing Properly Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, stripe-payments

Couldn't find why card details input of stripe is showing like this
**SS of Problem**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECdFt.png): [Input not showing properly]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aXRV.png): [Image of how it should be shown]

using Django

**here is my checkout.js**

```
    // Create a Stripe client. 
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51K4fECSGVkDCNvQ2xw1cHS4RcgdDEsYPDLy5vOJoG8a9whSkP53yscb57okeJQMRyDLawodCrJtjE05W0EgLu58s00Y2zFEz9V');
    
      // Create an instance of Elements.
      var elements = stripe.elements();
    
      // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
      // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
      var style = {
        base: {
          color: '#32325d',
          lineHeight: '18px',
          fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
          fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
          fontSize: '16px',
          '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4'
          }
        },
        invalid: {
          color: '#fa755a',
          iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
      };
    
      // Create an instance of the card Element.
      var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
    
      // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
      card.mount('#card-element');
    
      // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
      card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
          displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
          displayError.textContent = '';
        }
      });
    
      // Handle form submission.
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error.
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
          } else {
            // Send the token to your server.
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
          }
        });
    
      });
    
      var successElement = document.getElementById('stripe-token-handler');
      document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
        successElement.className = 'is-hidden';
      });
    
      function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        successElement.className = '';
        successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = token.id;
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
      }
```

**HERE IS CHECKOUT.css**

```
    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
    color: #6b7c93;
  }
  
  *, label {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-variant: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  
  button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #32325d;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 28px;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
    box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
    background-color: #43458b;
  }
  
  form {
    padding: 30px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  
  label {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  
  #card-errors {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    color: #fa755a;
  }
  
  .form-row {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .token {
    color: #32325d;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    width: 670px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #stripe-token-handler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 50px 100px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
      0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.15),
      0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  #stripe-token-handler.is-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  
  /**
   * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
   * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
   */
  .StripeElement {
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  }
  
  .StripeElement--focus {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
  }
  
  .StripeElement--invalid {
    border-color: #fa755a;
  }
  
  .StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
    background-color: #fefde5 !important;
  }
```

**HERE IS Payment_membership.html "Checkout.html"**

```
{% extends 'course/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/checkout.css' %}">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Payment</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p>Selected membership: {{ selected_membership }}</p>
            <p>Price: <strong>${{ selected_membership.price }}</strong><small>/month</small></p>


<button onclick="toggleDisplay();" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100%;">Checkout with a credit card</button>


<div id="collapseStripe" class="wrapper">
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <!-- can't do this -->
  <!-- <script src="{% static 'js/stripeV3.js' %}"></script> -->

  <form action="." method="post" id="payment-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;">
            <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame3" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-8a434729e4eb82355db4882974049278.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][lineHeight]=18px&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;features[noop]=false&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js%2Felements%2Fquickstart&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController0" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; height: 18px;">
            </iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;">
            <input class="__PrivateStripeElement-safariInput" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;">
        </div>
    </div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>

    <button>Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
  
  </div>
  
</div>

<div id="stripe-token-handler" class="is-hidden">Success! Got token: <span class="token"></span></div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- script for the stripe form -->
<script src="{% static 'javascript/checkout.js' %}"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- script for toggling display of the form -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDisplay() {
      var x = document.getElementById("collapseStripe");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
</script>


{% endblock  %}
```

**Also Here is Views.py of membership**

```
    from typing import Any
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from .models import Membership, UserMembership, Subscription
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.conf import settings
    
    import stripe
    # Create your views here.
    # LEARN TO CREATE django class base views
    
    #They are convientent methods as they are going to help us in work force.
    def get_user_membership(request):
          user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
          if user_membership_qs.exists():
                return user_membership_qs.first()
          return None
    
    #func for getting subscriptions of user
    def get_user_subscription(request):
          user_subscription_qs = Subscription.objects.filter(user_membership = get_user_membership(request))
    
          if user_subscription_qs.exists():
                user_subscription = user_subscription_qs.first()
                return user_subscription
          return None
    
    #Func for getting membership typ
    def get_selected_membership(request):
          membership_type = request.session['selected_membership_type']
          selected_membership_qs = Membership.objects.filter(membership_type=membership_type)
    
          if selected_membership_qs.exists():
                return selected_membership_qs.first()
          return None
    
class MembershipSelectView(ListView):
        model = Membership
    
        #Trying to take membership here so that we can compare it in the html Layout Template.
        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
                context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                current_membership = get_user_membership(self.request)
                context['current_membership'] = str(current_membership.membership)
                return context
        
        def post(self, request, **kwargs):
              #Trying to membership here
                selected_membership_type = request.POST.get('membership_type')
    
                user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
                user_subscription = get_user_subscription(request)
    
                selected_membership_qs = Membership.objects.filter(membership_type=selected_membership_type)
    
                if selected_membership_qs.exists():
                      selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()
    
          #VALIDATION
                      
                if user_membership.membership == selected_membership:
                      if user_subscription != None:
                            messages.info(request, "You already have this membership. Your next payment is due {}".format("get this value from stripe"))
                     
                      #It will redirect the user from the url he/she might have came from
                      return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
                
          #We are wanting to pass the selected membership into the session.
          #assing to the session
              request.session['selected_membership_type']=selected_membership.membership_type
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('membership:payment'))
        
    #Provide user with stripe payment form and handle actual payment
    def paymentView(request):
    
          user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
    
          selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)
          publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
          
          
     
          context = {
                'publishKey': publishKey,
                'selected_membership': selected_membership,
          }
    
          return render(request, "membership/payment_membership.html", context)
```

If needed anything else please ask, and any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your code, are you wanting to build a Django Form and pass that data to Stripe or are you simply attempting to embed an iFrame? Simple instructions on Stripe docs for python are here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/embedded/quickstart

Comment: I am following a YouTube video, on building a video subscription site, and before this page at(url/membership) user select his/her desired membership and come this page (url/membership/payment_membership), we show the user a form, credit card input + submit button to purchase. There is a Github link: https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/memberships/templates/memberships/membership_payment.html

Comment: checkout.js, checkout.css are outside in static folder